# В чем принципиальная разница DirectX и DirectX SDK?

Tags: directshow, directx

Здравствуйте.

Недавно начал изучать `DirectX`, и у меня возник вопрос.
Для написания программ использующих прямой доступ к видеоустройству необходим `DirectX SDK`.
В этом пакете находятся библиотеки с описанием функций, структур, типов данных, а так же заголовочные файлы, включаемые в создаваемую программу.
Далее написанный код преобразуется компилятором в объектный и пакуется в исполняемый файл или динамическую библиотеку.
Так вот, сам вопрос: Почему для запуска исполняемого файла(те же игры) нужен именно `DirecX`, хотя для его создания был необходим `DirectX SDK`? И чем именно `DirectX` отличается от `DirectX SDK`?

Заранее извиняюсь если что-то не правильно написал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sdk - это набор для программиста, что бы он мог создавать приложения. А вот конечному пользователю нужен небольшой набор файлов с sdk (обычно это называют run time или подобное) для того, что бы оно работало.

Например. Программисту, что бы написать, нужна dll, заголовочный файл к ней и документация. А ещё и какие-нибудь воспомогательные утилиты. Это и будет sdk, а пользователю обычно нужна только dll.

Comment: То есть чисто теоретически возможно, что для создания такого рода приложения хватит и обычного `DirectX`? Если например тебе не нужна документация, ты и так все знаешь, а утилиты не пригодятся.

Comment: нет. не хватит. Для того, что бы скомпилировать, нужны будут заголовочные файлы (как минимум). В обычном DirectX их нет (они там не нужны). Конечно, их можно написать руками, но придется угадать сигнатуры и тому подобное.